# Problems using Handlebars.compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I've trying to get handlebar to install for precompiling templates. I've followed the installation instructions (http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html), and I do not appear to have any problem running the installation (see below). However when I issue the compile command ...

```
handlebars users.handlebars -f templates.js
```

the handlebars command can not be found.

```
-bash: handlebars: command not found
```

Would love to get a clue on this one.

```
(username) ~$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
(username) ~$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
(username) ~$ npm install -g handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/handlebars -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars
handlebars@1.0.7 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/handlebars
├── uglify-js@1.2.6
└── optimist@0.3.4 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
(username) ~$ cd Sites/projectone/templates/
(username) ~/Sites/projectone/templates (master)$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 username  ec_earth  102 Sep 26 23:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 username  ec_earth  340 Sep 26 23:58 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 username  ec_earth   17 Sep 26 23:57 users.handlebars
(username) ~/Sites/projectone/templates (master)$ handlebars users.handlebars -f templates.js
-bash: handlebars: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the full path to the `node_modules/.bin` directory (they aren't automatically added to your path).

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/.bin/handlebars users.handlebars -f template.js
```

Comment: Dear @Bill I have a very similar problem. But I cannot seem to find the right path. what I have is `c:\users\b\downloads\node-v7.1.0-win-x64\node_modules` then I have two possible folders `handlebars` and `npm`. Inside, handlebars I have `node_modules/.bin` but then there is no `handlebars` inside... Any help? Thanks